# how to return string html as react child

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, string

I want to return my string as html for react child
assuming string as `"<div><span>test</span></div>"`
and assuming we have a react function component like below:

```
 function StrToElement({ str }) {  
 const element = new DOMParser().parseFromString(str, "text/html").body.childNodes[0];
 return <pre>{element}</pre>;
}
```

but the above code throws this error:

> Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Text])

Comment: What is the type of element when you inspect it in the debugger? I’m guessing it’s not a string, which is why React is complaining.

Comment: when i use console.log(element) it return `<div><span>test</span></div>` but when i use `typeof element` it return  object

Comment: Right. I’m guessing that’s your problem. I believe you need to to convert element to a string in some way before putting it into a <pre> tag body in that way, which would explain the error. Maybe try setting element to “test” and see if it works, and if so then try converting the original element object to a string (not sure the best way)?

Comment: i want a way that it work like a html tag not just as string. if i pass it as simple string it will not behave like a real tag

Answer (score 1):

You may use dangerouslySetInnerHTML property inside your element.

It will look like this

```
 function StrToElement({ str }) { 
   return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: str}}>{element}</div>;
 }
```

or maybe you could assign it directly without creating new component

[Reference](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml)

Comment: word dangerously refer to =>(it is not safe way)